# Graphics are blocked out when I add a JPanel to the frame (java)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, graphics2d, mouselistener

I have some Graphics2D graphics displayed in my frame, and then I added a JPanel to the entire frame so that I can add a mouselistener to clicks anywhere in the panel. However, the graphics disappear, I assume blocked out by the frame. I tried setting the panel to visible false, but that didnt do anything. How can I keep my mouselistener listening on the entire window, and still display my graphics?

EDIT:
Heres a bit of code: EDIT:(and some more)

```
//adding the panel and mouselistener
JPanel allPanel = new JPanel();
allPanel.addMouseListener(this);
frame.add(allPanel);


//...
//drawing some of the graphics
public void draw() {



    frame.add(new CustomPaintComponent());
    // Display the frame

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    JPanel allPanel = new JPanel();
    allPanel.addMouseListener(this);
    frame.add(allPanel);
      }


      static class CustomPaintComponent extends Component {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
      g2d.fillRoundRect(10, 10, 50, 50, 10,10);

      //...
```

Comment: Can you tell us a little more about your problem? Maybe you could give some code.

Comment: what else exactly would it be helpful to know? I don't think my code would be too helpful, but I could add a little.

Comment: As it is right now, I have no idea what your problem is. You say you have graphics displayed in your frame, but how is it displayed?

Comment: I edited to add code to show how the graphics are displayed

Comment: Where in the frame is the graphics displayed? in the `paint` method? in the `paintComponent` method?

Comment: Can you show more code please?

Comment: It is likely the that JPanel is opaque, therefore covering over what is painted below it. But won't a runnable example, it's no possible to know for sure...

Comment: I showed even more code about how the graphics are displayed

Comment: *"How can I keep my mouselistener listening on the entire window, and still display my graphics?"* - the short answer is can't, not without a lot of messing about, but with an example of what you've tried, it's all assumption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three problems jump out...

First, `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` as its default layout manager, this means that only one component can occupy any of its available five positions. By using `add(Component)` you add each component to the `CENTRE` position, overriding the first component you added to it...

Second, `JPanel` is opaque by default, meaning, even if you did get both components to occupy the same space, the top component would block the lower one

Third, you should be using `paintComponent` instead of `paint`

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

The solution could be to add the `MouseListener` directly to the custom component

Another choice would be to use a `BorderLayout` on the lower component, make the top component transparent (using `setOpaque(false)`) and add it to the lower component directly...

Comment: how would I add the MouseListener to the custom component?

Comment: `customComponent.addMouseListener(...)`?

Comment: Thats what i thought but I tried customComponent.addMouseListener(this) inside my paint method and it didn't work. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: *"Did I do something wrong?"* - Yes, do nothing in any of the `paint` methods but paint, do not modify the state of the components.  Either add the listener after you have created an instance of the component, assuming you want an "external" listener or within the constructor assuming you want a "inner" listener

Comment: This is what I tried:


     frame.add(new CustomPaintComponent());
     CustomPaintComponent.addMouseListener(this);


but it gives an error:
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method addMouseListener(MouseListener) from the type Component

Comment: Probably because `CustomPaintComponent` isn't an instance of `CustomPaintComponent`. Try creating a instance of `CustomPaintComponent`, adding that instance to the frame AND adding the `MouseListener` to the same instance

Comment: YES!!! I did that and it worked, and showed everything while alowing me to keep mouselistener!
Thanks so much for helping me with so much!

Comment: answer accepted especially for the "The solution could be to add the MouseListener directly to the custom component"

Answer (score 4):

I believe your problem is that `JFrame` can have only one component added to it (by default). You add a `CustomPaintComponent`, which paints your graphics. Then, you add the `JPanel`, which automatically removes the `CustomPaintComponent`

Are you trying to paint the custom drawing on top of the `JPanel`? If that is the case, simply move that code over to the `JPanel` (but instead of using a `CustomPaintComponent`, put it in the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of the JPanel)